# Are AVL trees equal?

Tags: java, algorithm, unit-testing, tree, interview-questions

I was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9597220/1065835) and decided to implement an AVL tree with the methods `equals` and `hashCode` as if I was asked to do that at a job interview.

This is my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/MaksimDmitriev/Are-Trees-Equal/tree/rev1).

In addition to the solution itself, I wrote tests for all the possible cases. If I missed something, or if my solution has any bugs, please let me know.

**AvlTree**

```
package com.bst;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class AvlTree {

    Node mRoot;

    public AvlTree() {

    }

    public AvlTree(int root) {
        mRoot = new Node(root);
    }

    private Node insert(Node root, int key) {
        if (root == null) {
            return new Node(key);
        }
        if (key < root.mValue) {
            root.mLeft = insert(root.mLeft, key);
        } else {
            root.mRight = insert(root.mRight, key);
        }
        return balance(root);
    }

    private Node balance(Node p) {
        fixHeight(p);
        if (bfactor(p) == 2) {
            if (bfactor(p.mRight) < 0) {
                p.mRight = rotateRight(p.mRight);
            }
            return rotateLeft(p);
        }
        if (bfactor(p) == -2) {
            if (bfactor(p.mLeft) > 0) {
                p.mLeft = rotateLeft(p.mLeft);
            }
            return rotateRight(p);
        }
        return p;
    }

    private Node rotateRight(Node p) {
        Node q = p.mLeft;
        p.mLeft = q.mRight;
        q.mRight = p;
        fixHeight(p);
        fixHeight(q);
        return q;
    }

    private Node rotateLeft(Node q) {
        Node p = q.mRight;
        q.mRight = p.mLeft;
        p.mLeft = q;
        fixHeight(q);
        fixHeight(p);
        return p;
    }

    private int height(Node p) {
        return p == null ? 0 : p.mHeight;
    }

    private int bfactor(Node p) {
        return height(p.mRight) - height(p.mLeft);
    }

    private void fixHeight(Node p) {
        int hl = height(p.mLeft);
        int hr = height(p.mRight);
        p.mHeight = (hl > hr ? hl : hr) + 1;
    }

    public void insert(int... keys) {
        for (int value : keys) {
            mRoot = insert(mRoot, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        if (this == arg0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(arg0 instanceof AvlTree)) {
            return false;
        }
        AvlTree another = (AvlTree) arg0;
        return areTreesEqual(this.mRoot, another.mRoot);
    }

    private boolean areTreesEqual(Node root1, Node root2) {
        if (root1 == root2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (root1 == null || root2 == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return root1.mValue == root2.mValue && areTreesEqual(root1.mLeft, root2.mLeft) && areTreesEqual(root1.mRight, root2.mRight);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (mRoot == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        LinkedList<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<AvlTree.Node>();
        nodes.add(mRoot);
        int res = 17;
        while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
            Node head = nodes.remove();
            res = 31 * res + head.hashCode();
            if (head.mLeft != null) {
                nodes.addLast(head.mLeft);
            }
            if (head.mRight != null) {
                nodes.addLast(head.mRight);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (mRoot == null) {
            return "[]";
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");
        inOrderPrint(mRoot, builder);
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - 2);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private void inOrderPrint(Node root, StringBuilder builder) {
        if (root != null) {
            inOrderPrint(root.mLeft, builder);
            builder.append(root + ", ");
            inOrderPrint(root.mRight, builder);
        }
    }

    static class Node {

        Node mLeft;
        Node mRight;
        final int mValue;
        private int mHeight;

        private Node(int value) {
            mValue = value;
            mHeight = 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int res = 17;
            res = 17 * res + mValue;
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Integer.toString(mValue);
        }
    }

}
```

**AvlTreeTest**

```
package com.bst;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AvlTreeTest {

    @Test
    public void testDefaultConstructor() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree();
        Assert.assertNull(t1.mRoot);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIntegerConstructor() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(1);
        Assert.assertNotNull(t1.mRoot);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertToEmptyTree() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree();
        t1.insert(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, t1.mRoot.mValue);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEqualsItself() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree();
        Assert.assertEquals(t1, t1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotEqualNotAvlInstance() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree();
        Object object = new Object();
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, object);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyEqual() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree();
        AvlTree t2 = new AvlTree();
        Assert.assertEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFirstEmpty() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree();
        AvlTree t2 = new AvlTree(1);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSecondEmpty() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(1);
        AvlTree t2 = new AvlTree();
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRootsEqual() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(1);
        AvlTree t2 = new AvlTree(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRootAndLeftEqual() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(10);
        t1.insert(2);
        AvlTree t2 = new AvlTree(10);
        t2.insert(2);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRootAndRightEqual() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(1);
        t1.insert(2);
        AvlTree t2 = new AvlTree(1);
        t2.insert(2);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRootsEqual_LeftsNotEqual() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(10);
        t1.insert(2);
        AvlTree t2 = new AvlTree(10);
        t2.insert(1);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRootsEqual_RightsNotEqual() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(1);
        t1.insert(2);
        AvlTree t2 = new AvlTree(1);
        t2.insert(4);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyTreeHashCode() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree();
        Assert.assertEquals(0, t1.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEqualTreesEqualHashCodes() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(10);
        t1.insert(2, 12);
        AvlTree t2 = new AvlTree(10);
        t2.insert(2, 12);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.hashCode(), t2.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testToStringEmpty() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree();
        Assert.assertEquals("[]", t1.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testToStringSingleNode() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(1);
        Assert.assertEquals("[1]", t1.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testToStringManyNodes() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(1);
        t1.insert(12, 56, 7, 2, 1);
        Assert.assertEquals("[1, 1, 2, 7, 12, 56]", t1.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleRotateLeft() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(10);
        t1.insert(14, 56);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mValue, 14);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mLeft.mValue, 10);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mRight.mValue, 56);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleRotateRight() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(10);
        t1.insert(2, 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mValue, 2);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mLeft.mValue, 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mRight.mValue, 10);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoubleRotateLeftRight() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(10);
        t1.insert(4, 9);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mValue, 9);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mLeft.mValue, 4);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mRight.mValue, 10);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoubleRotateRightLeft() {
        AvlTree t1 = new AvlTree(10);
        t1.insert(14, 12);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mValue, 12);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mLeft.mValue, 10);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.mRoot.mRight.mValue, 14);
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it seems to be all right. The tests passes? But you should get rid of the member prefix. In Java you didn't use them. And use long names like `branchFactor()` instead of `bFactor()`.

Comment: @Xean, which prefix do you mean?

Comment: The little m in front of each member variable of a class, like in the Node class.

Comment: @Xean, the m prefix is part of [the Android coding style.](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) I find m prefixes helpful because using them I can easily distinguish between class fields and local variables. And `bFactor` is a **balance** factor

Comment: @Xean, all the tests pass. Just download the project from [Github](https://github.com/MaksimDmitriev/Are-Trees-Equal/tree/rev1) and run it.I also used [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) to make sure that all the branches of code were covered.

Comment: learning never stops, I didn't work with android yet ;-) ok, if this is for an android app it is fine. But in general these are Google/android specific coding standards but not Java coding standards.

Comment: @Xean, the AVL tree is not for an Android app. I just find the Android style helpful. And I got used to it because I am an Android developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Testing all possible cases

> In addition to the solution itself, I wrote tests for all the possible cases.

It seems you have verified all execution paths are covered.
That's great,
but it doesn't mean you have tested "all the possible cases",
far from it.

Code coverage (also known as *structured basis testing*) is but one of the dimensions of testing.
Another dimension is *data-flow testing*,
which is just as important, and can be very tricky.

Testing all possible cases is in general not feasible:
you'd have to enumerate all conceivable inputs,
which is impossible.
There are a couple of things you can do:

- Test with "interesting" data sets
- Test boundaries, corner cases
- Test combinations of the above

Consider this, for example:

```
AvlTree tree = new AvlTree();
tree.insert(1, 1, 1);
```

What will happen:

1. The first 1 is set as root
2. The second 1 is set as root -> right
3. The second 1 is set as root -> right -> right
4. The tree is rebalanced, rotating to the left, with 1 as root, and 1 as left node and 1 as right node

From this we gain some interesting insights:

- The tree implementation allows duplicates: an unusual, and potentially troublesome feature
- The outcome of the rotation is smelly: the implementation of `insert` uses strictly `<` to arrange elements to the left sub-tree, which the rotation breaks

I suggest to add more test cases with larger test trees.
Think of node sequences that will trigger interesting rotations.
Testing `hashCode` with empty tree and trees with 2 nodes is hardly sufficient.

For more details about data-flow testing,
check out Chapter 22 in [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/).

#### To allow duplicate values or not

Allowing duplicate nodes in a binary search tree is unusual,
and invites all kinds of problems.
In addition to the code smell I highlighted earlier,
you'll probably have some headaches when implementing deletion.
For example `tree.insert(3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1)` results in this tree:

> ```
>     3
>    / \
>   1   3
>  / \   \
> 1   3   3
>    /
>   1
> ```

Given such tree, what should happen on `delete(3)` ? Remove the first?

How to delete all nodes with 3? Keep removing until nothing is removed?

You could save yourself a lot of headaches by simply not allowing duplicates.

#### Adopting Android coding practices in plain Java code

I do understand your sentiment for linking the "m" prefix convention used in Android development.
If you want to stick with it, that's up to you,
but let me remind you of some concerns:

1. In expressions like `root.mLeft`, you don't need the "m" to clarify it's a member variable: `root.left` is perfectly clear too
2. In the few places where it might not be obvious, as in `mRoot = insert(mRoot, value)`, you can always use `this.root = ...` to clarify

Looking over the code, most uses cases fall in the first category, and the second is so rare than despite "this." being longer than "m". By using the `this.` prefix where ambiguous and dropping the `m` prefix, you will get shorter, perfectly unambiguous code that won't put off any Java developers.
Food for thought ;-)

Lastly,
[it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092098/why-most-of-android-tutorials-variables-start-with-m) that the "m"-prefix is required for code to be contributed to the Android Open Source Project,
and not really a style guide for the code of individual Android apps.

#### `LinkedList` as a `Queue`

In the implementation of `hashCode`,
you're using `LinkedList<Node> nodes` as a queue.
So I suggest to declare it as a `Queue`,
name the variable "queue",
and instead of the `remove()` method,
use the more natural `poll()`.

#### Naming

I find it a bit confusing that in `insert(Node root, int key) { ... }` the parameter variable is named "root":
it may mislead that the function manipulates the tree root,
when in fact it's most often an intermediary node.
I suggest to rename the variable to "node" instead.

In other methods you name a `Node` parameter `p`.
I'd suggest the more intuitive `node` everywhere.
And where you use `q` I'd suggest `other`.

In the implementation of `equals`,
you call the other node "another".
I suggest using "other", which is just more common.

Comment: > I'd suggest the more intuitive node everywhere.
I'd prefer `parent` because finally an inserted node a child of a higher node.

Comment: Queue is an interface. Would you use LinkedList as an actual type? And why would you prefer poll() over remove()?

Comment: Yes, I suggest to use `Queue<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<AvlTree.Node>();`, and rename "nodes" to "queue". I thought "poll" is a more natural name for removing the first element of a Queue. But it seems I was wrong about that. Wikipedia doesn't even mention the term. And looking at the JavaDoc, there's a difference in the behavior as well, of `poll()` and `remove()`. In your example, it doesn't matter which you choose.

Comment: Why do you think it's better to store the reference to the linked list in the queue? I can call it `queue` but use LinkedList as a reference type and an actual type. `LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<AvlTree.Node>();`

Comment: "store the reference to the linked list in the queue" means something else, means putting a linked list inside a queue. What I'm suggesting is to *refer* to `nodes` by the interface type `Queue` instead of the implementation type `LinkedList`. Because the logic of your usage is the concept of a queue. So I'm suggesting to call a queue what it is: a queue. This is also related to the general recommendation of referring to objects by their interfaces, as explained in Joshua Bloch: Effective Java, Item 52

Comment: As to p and q for node names, these name are good because I often draw something out when I'm solving a problem on algorithms

Comment: About data flow testing. Do you know a plugin or something for Eclipse which can create a graph by the given source code? All I found was horribly dated and didn't work

Comment: I don't know such plugin, but I haven't researched it.