# Are AVL trees equal? - revision 3

Tags: java, algorithm, unit-testing, interview-questions

[The original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9597220/1065835)

> Given two binary trees, return true if they are structurally
>   identical, and false otherwise.

[Are AVL trees equal?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/101308/23821)

[Are AVL trees equal? - revision 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/106215/23821)

[This revision on GitHub](https://github.com/MaksimDmitriev/Are-Trees-Equal/tree/rev3-fix)

In this revision:

- `equals()` is documented. Two trees are equal if they are structurally identical.
- `AvlTree` has a type parameter `T extends Comparable<T>`.
- Sizes of compared trees are used as a quick rejection. But I tested insertion of 10M items to two trees. There is no performance benefit in using `size`. The result is shown below.

**AvlTree.**

```
package com.bst;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class AvlTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    Node<T> root;
    private int size;

    public AvlTree() {
    }

    public AvlTree(T... keys) {
        insert(keys);
    }

    private Node<T> insert(Node<T> parent, T key) {
        if (parent == null) {
            size++;
            return new Node<T>(key);
        }
        if (key.compareTo(parent.key) < 0) {
            parent.left = insert(parent.left, key);
        } else if (key.compareTo(parent.key) > 0) {
            parent.right = insert(parent.right, key);
        }
        return balance(parent);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    private Node<T> balance(Node<T> p) {
        fixHeight(p);
        if (bfactor(p) == 2) {
            if (bfactor(p.right) < 0) {
                p.right = rotateRight(p.right);
            }
            return rotateLeft(p);
        }
        if (bfactor(p) == -2) {
            if (bfactor(p.left) > 0) {
                p.left = rotateLeft(p.left);
            }
            return rotateRight(p);
        }
        return p;
    }

    private Node<T> rotateRight(Node<T> p) {
        Node<T> q = p.left;
        p.left = q.right;
        q.right = p;
        fixHeight(p);
        fixHeight(q);
        return q;
    }

    private Node<T> rotateLeft(Node<T> q) {
        Node<T> p = q.right;
        q.right = p.left;
        p.left = q;
        fixHeight(q);
        fixHeight(p);
        return p;
    }

    private int height(Node<T> p) {
        return p == null ? 0 : p.height;
    }

    private int bfactor(Node<T> p) {
        return height(p.right) - height(p.left);
    }

    private void fixHeight(Node<T> p) {
        int hl = height(p.left);
        int hr = height(p.right);
        p.height = (hl > hr ? hl : hr) + 1;
    }

    public void insert(T... keys) {
        if (keys == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (T key : keys) {
            if (key == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Can't insert null");
            }
            root = insert(root, key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        if (this == arg0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(arg0 instanceof AvlTree)) {
            return false;
        }
        AvlTree other = (AvlTree) arg0; 
        // size == other.size && 
        return areTreesEqual(this.root, other.root);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param root1 the root of the first tree
     * @param root2 the root of the second tree
     * @return true if the trees with the given roots are structurally identical, 
     * false otherwise
     */
    private boolean areTreesEqual(Node<T> root1, Node<T> root2) {
        if (root1 == root2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (root1 == null || root2 == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return root1.equals(root2) && areTreesEqual(root1.left, root2.left) && areTreesEqual(root1.right, root2.right);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        Queue<Node<T>> nodes = new LinkedList<Node<T>>();
        nodes.add(root);
        int res = 17;
        while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
            Node<T> head = nodes.remove();
            res = 31 * res + head.hashCode();
            if (head.left != null) {
                nodes.add(head.left);
            }
            if (head.right != null) {
                nodes.add(head.right);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (root == null) {
            return "[]";
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");
        inOrderPrint(root, builder);
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - 2);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private void inOrderPrint(Node<T> root, StringBuilder builder) {
        if (root != null) {
            inOrderPrint(root.left, builder);
            builder.append(root + ", ");
            inOrderPrint(root.right, builder);
        }
    }

    static final class Node<T> {

        Node<T> left;
        Node<T> right;
        final T key;
        private int height;

        Node(T key) {
            this.key = key;
            this.height = 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return key.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof Node)) {
                return false;
            }
            Node other = (Node) obj;
            return key.equals(other.key); 
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return key.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

**AvlTreeTest (Unit tests)**

```
package com.bst;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.bst.AvlTree.Node;

public class AvlTreeTest {

    @Test
    public void testTwoEmptyTrees() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        Assert.assertEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLeftEmptyTree() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>(12);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRightEmptyTree() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(12);
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEqualsItself() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        Assert.assertEquals(t1, t1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotEqualNotAvlInstance() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        Object object = new Object();
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, object);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotequalSizes() {
        final int min = 0;
        final int max = 100000;
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        insertRange(t1, min, max);
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        insertRange(t2, min, max + 1);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStructurallyNotIdentical() {
        final int min = 0;
        final int max = 100000;
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        insertRange(t1, min, max);
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        insertRange(t2, min + 1, max + 1);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStructurallIdentical() {
        final int min = 0;
        final int max = 100000;
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        insertRange(t1, min, max);
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        insertRange(t2, min, max);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLeftNodeMissing() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10, 4, 18, 2, 20);
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10, 4, 18, 6, 20);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRightNodeMissing() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10, 4);
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10, 4, 18);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLeftNodesNotEqual() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10, 3, 18);
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10, 4, 18);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRightNodesNotEqual() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10, 4, 16);
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10, 4, 18);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRootNodesNotEqual() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(12, 3, 45);
        AvlTree<Integer> t2 = new AvlTree<Integer>(13, 3, 45);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(t1, t2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyTreeHashCode() {
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        Assert.assertEquals(0, avlTree.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleZeroNodeTreeHashCode() {
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree = new AvlTree<Integer>(0);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(0, avlTree.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRootAndLeftNodesTreeHashCode() {
        Integer[] nodes = new Integer[] {12, 3};
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree = new AvlTree<Integer>(nodes);
        int res = 17;
        res = 31 * res + nodes[0].hashCode();
        res = 31 * res + nodes[1].hashCode();
        Assert.assertEquals(res, avlTree.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRootAndRightNodesTreeHashCode() {
        Integer[] nodes = new Integer[] {12, 30};
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree = new AvlTree<Integer>(nodes);
        int res = 17;
        res = 31 * res + nodes[0].hashCode();
        res = 31 * res + nodes[1].hashCode();
        Assert.assertEquals(res, avlTree.hashCode());
    }

    private void insertRange(AvlTree<Integer> tree, int min, int max) {
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
            tree.insert(i);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testEqualTreesEqualHashCodes() {
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(1, 2, 3);
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree2 = new AvlTree<Integer>(1, 2, 3);
        Assert.assertEquals(avlTree1.hashCode(), avlTree2.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleRotateLeft() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10);
        t1.insert(14, 56);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.key, Integer.valueOf(14));
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.left.key, Integer.valueOf(10));
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.right.key, Integer.valueOf(56));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleRotateRight() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10);
        t1.insert(2, 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.key, Integer.valueOf(2));
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.left.key, Integer.valueOf(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.right.key, Integer.valueOf(10));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoubleRotateLeftRight() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10);
        t1.insert(4, 9);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.key, Integer.valueOf(9));
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.left.key, Integer.valueOf(4));
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.right.key, Integer.valueOf(10));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoubleRotateRightLeft() {
        AvlTree<Integer> t1 = new AvlTree<Integer>(10);
        t1.insert(14, 12);
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.key, Integer.valueOf(12));
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.left.key, Integer.valueOf(10));
        Assert.assertEquals(t1.root.right.key, Integer.valueOf(14));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertDuplicate() {
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree = new AvlTree<Integer>(12, 12);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, avlTree.getSize());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitWithNull() {
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree = new AvlTree<Integer>(null);
        Assert.assertNull(null, avlTree.root);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testInsertNull() {
        Integer[] nodes = {
                12, null
        };
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree = new AvlTree<Integer>(nodes);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNodeEqual() {
        Node<Integer> node = new Node<Integer>(1);
        Node<Integer> node2 = node;
        Assert.assertEquals(node, node2);
    }

}
```

I insert items from 0 (inclusive) to 10,000,0000 (exclusive) to the two trees. And the execution time of the first `fillTree()` is four times as long as the execution time of the second `fillTree()`. I think the JVM just reuses some/all nodes I previously used. And `equal()` works very fast (0.221 sec.). For example, `fillTree(start, count);` and `fillTree(start, count);`

```
package com.client;

import com.bst.AvlTree;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Client code goes here
        final int start = 0;
        final int count = 10000000; 
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree1 = fillTree(start, count);
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree2 = fillTree(count, 2 * count);
        long startTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(avlTree1.equals(avlTree2));
        printDuration("equals: ", startTimeStamp, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    private static AvlTree<Integer> fillTree(int start, int count) {
        AvlTree<Integer> avlTree = new AvlTree<Integer>();
        long startTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = start; i < start + count; i++) {
            avlTree.insert(i);
        }
        printDuration("Insertion: ", startTimeStamp, System.currentTimeMillis());
        return avlTree;
    }

    private static void printDuration(String operation, long start, long end) {
        System.out.println(operation + (end - start) / 1000.0);
    }
}
```

> Insertion: 11.758
>
> 10000000
>
> Insertion: 3.802
>
> equals: 0.221

If the second tree contains values that are not presented in the first tree, the second call of `fillTree()` will take twice as long as the first one. Maybe because heap is already filled with 10M items. For example, `fillTree(start, count);` and `fillTree(count, 2 * count);`

> Insertion: 12.196
>
> Insertion: 24.109
>
> false
>
> equals: 0.0

Comment: With `AvlTree.insert()` (implicitly) using `0 == T.compareTo()`, wouldn't it be wiser to either use that in `areTreesEqual()`, or document that `T.compareTo()` shall be consistent with `T.equals()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    p.height = (hl > hr ? hl : hr) + 1;
```

For this sort of stuff you should use `Math.max`. It reads better. The JVM will handle inlining if it is needed.

I can't really find any other in-code improvements.